# XHR request fails in Scrapy but works in python-requests

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest, scrapy, httprequest, python-requests

I'm trying to get data from a site using Ajax,I just smiulate the XHR request with headers and body, and I get a 400 response telling me that the request is not allowed. This is my code:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy import Request, FormRequest
import json

class jsonSpider(Spider):
    name = 'json'

    start_urls = [
        'http://m.ctrip.com/restapi/soa2/10932/hotel/Product/domestichotelget']

    def start_requests(self):
        headers = {
            "Host": "m.ctrip.com",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "cookieOrigin": "http://wap.ctrip.com",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Referer": "http://wap.ctrip.com/webapp/hotel/hoteldetail/426638.html?days=1&atime=20160623&contrl=2&num=1&biz=1",
            "Content-Length": "455",
            "Origin": "http://wap.ctrip.com",
            "Connection": "keep-alive"}
        data = '{"biz":1,"contrl":3,"facility":0,"faclist":[],"key":"","keytp":0,"pay":0,"querys":[],"couponlist":[],"setInfo":{"cityId":2,"dstId":0,"inDay":"2016-06-24","outDay":"2016-06-25"},"sort":{"dir":1,"idx":70,"ordby":0,"size":100},"qbitmap":0,"alliance":{"ishybrid":0},"head":{"ctok":"","cver":"1.0","lang":"01","sid":"8888","syscode":"09","auth":null,"extension":[{"name":"pageid","value":"212093"},{"name":"webp","value":0},{"name":"protocal","value":"http"}]},"contentType":"json"}'
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(
                url,
                self.parse,
                method='POST',
                headers=headers,
                body=data
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.body
        print(page)
```

but when I simulate XHR with python requests,it works fine and got json response,this is my code uses requests:

```
import requests

url = 'http://m.ctrip.com/restapi/soa2/10932/hotel/Product/domestichotelget'
headers = {
    "Host": "m.ctrip.com",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "cookieOrigin": "http://wap.ctrip.com",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Referer": "http://wap.ctrip.com/webapp/hotel/hoteldetail/426638.html?days=1&atime=20160623&contrl=2&num=1&biz=1",
    "Content-Length": "455",
    "Origin": "http://wap.ctrip.com",
    "Connection": "keep-alive"}
body = '{"biz":1,"contrl":3,"facility":0,"faclist":[],"key":"","keytp":0,"pay":0,"querys":[],"couponlist":[],"setInfo":{"cityId":2,"dstId":0,"inDay":"2016-06-24","outDay":"2016-06-25"},"sort":{"dir":1,"idx":70,"ordby":0,"size":100},"qbitmap":0,"alliance":{"ishybrid":0},"head":{"ctok":"","cver":"1.0","lang":"01","sid":"8888","syscode":"09","auth":null,"extension":[{"name":"pageid","value":"212093"},{"name":"webp","value":0},{"name":"protocal","value":"http"}]},"contentType":"json"}'


response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body).content
print(response)
```

what's wrong with my scrapy code?

Answer (score 3):

Remove `"Content-Length": "455",` in your headers and let Scrapy calculate itself. Your `data` is 477 bytes long, so the server, I guess, takes the first 455 bytes of the incoming data and fails to parse as JSON as it is not complete and returns 400 which means `Bad Request`.

Comment: Could you explain why that same headers works using Python Requests and not using Scrapy?

Comment: Because python requests apparently re-calculates the size and overrides the existing `Content-Length` in header whilst scrapy just adds another `Content-Length`, this is captured by wireshark when scrapy request is made:

`Content-Length: 477\r\n Origin: http://wap.ctrip.com\r\nContent-Length: 455\r\n`

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you it gave 200 response for following code

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy import Request, FormRequest
import json


class jsonSpider(Spider):
   name = 'json_spider'

   start_urls = [
    'http://m.ctrip.com/restapi/soa2/10932/hotel/Product/domestichotelget']

   def start_requests(self):
      headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Connection": "keep-alive"}
      data = {"biz":1,"contrl":3,"facility":0,"faclist":[],"key":"","keytp":0,"pay":0,"querys":[],"couponlist":[],"setInfo":{"cityId":2,"dstId":0,"inDay":"2016-06-24","outDay":"2016-06-25"},"sort":{"dir":1,"idx":70,"ordby":0,"size":100},"qbitmap":0,"alliance":{"ishybrid":0},"head":{"ctok":"","cver":"1.0","lang":"01","sid":"8888","syscode":"09","auth":None,"extension":[{"name":"pageid","value":"212093"},{"name":"webp","value":0},{"name":"protocal","value":"http"}]},"contentType":"json"}
      for url in self.start_urls:
         yield Request(
                url,
                self.parse,
                method='POST',
                headers=headers,
                body=json.dumps(data)
        )

   def parse(self, response):
     page = response.body
     print(page)
```

Comment: Could you explain why that same headers work in Python requests and not using Scrapy?

Comment: @Metalloy In scrapy headers we only describe accept-encoding, content-type, accept etc. If we provide content length which can be vary which can cause bad request